# Dynamic slideshow plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I need a slideshow that can be updated dynamically - for example new slides added on the fly or all slides resized.

In the past, I have been using Nivo slider, which works fine for slideshows when images are pre-loaded, but has some issues dealing with dynamic content. Any other plugin to recommend that would be better adapted to my scenario?

Other than the ability to update images, I need transition effects (fade is good enough), navigation (previous-next arrows) and caption.

Comment: I always respond the same way: http://sliderjs.org/

Comment: You can checkout out http://jsantell.com/presentr/#slide1. I have never used it but it looks like it may work for you.

Comment: @MikeRobinson thx. I just tested it and it looks promising, but the lack of support for older browsers (no fade) is an issue in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research and came across the [Really Simple Slideshow](http://reallysimpleworks.com/slideshow/). The last version is from April 19. From my first tests, it is pretty neat and addresses all the issues I had with Nivo slider (for example select the size, and avoid an image load at each image refresh).

What surprises me is that this slider is never mentioned in slideshow reviews. I'd be interested in feedback if others have experimented with it.